Spatie UUID model_has_role model_id return 0 when assignRole()
I'm trying to use UUID for spatie, and followed the instruction from official document. Everything went well until I have to assignRole to user.
It return 0

Where it should have same value as role_id

these are my codes following the guide
config/permission.php
'models' => [

    'permission' => \App\Models\Permission::class,

    'role' => \App\Models\Role::class,

],
'column_names' => [
    'role_pivot_key' => null, //default 'role_id',
    'permission_pivot_key' => null, //default 'permission_id',


    'model_morph_key' => 'model_ulid',


    'team_foreign_key' => 'team_id',
],

user seeder
$user = User::create([
    .
    .
    .
]);

// Set TeamId
setPermissionsTeamId(1);

$user->assignRole('superadmin');

both of my role and permission models
class Role extends SpatieRole
{
    use HasFactory, HasUlids;

    protected $primaryKey = 'ulid';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'guard_name',
    ];

}


Found the issues here, I did some debugging on Spatie's code itself, and found out that when I tried inserting new user model, it has id of 0.
public function assignRole(...$roles)
{
    $roles = $this->collectRoles($roles);

    $model = $this->getModel();
    $teamPivot = app(PermissionRegistrar::class)->teams && ! is_a($this, Permission::class) ?
        [app(PermissionRegistrar::class)->teamsKey => getPermissionsTeamId()] : [];

    if ($model->exists) {
        $currentRoles = $this->roles->map(fn ($role) => $role->getKey())->toArray();
        \DB::enableQueryLog(); // add this line
        dump($this); // add this line
        dump(array_diff($roles, $currentRoles), $teamPivot); // add this line
        dump($roles, $currentRoles); // add this line
        $this->roles()->attach(array_diff($roles, $currentRoles), $teamPivot);
        dump(\DB::getQueryLog()); // add this line
        $model->unsetRelation('roles');
    }
    .
    . 
    .
}

Shown result from dump($this) is this
#attributes: array:9 [
    "id" => 0
    "name" => "superadmin"
    "email" => "superadmin@mail.com"
    "email_verified_at" => "2024-06-06 13:47:23"
    "password" => "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi"
    "active" => 1
    "remember_token" => "U3feZKOcyA"
    "updated_at" => "2024-06-06 13:47:23"
    "created_at" => "2024-06-06 13:47:23"
  ]

So in the end I add public $incrementing = false; on User Models and it solved the problems
